# How to set ip, jumbo frame, receive buffers properties to Intel(R) Ethernet Server Adapter I350-T2 cards on Windows?

Tags: windows, network-programming

We have to set ip, jumbo frame, receive buffers properties to `Intel(R) Ethernet Server Adapter I350-T2` network cards (lot of them) on Windows7.
 Unfortunately when we do a disk image, these values are lost and we have to input all of them manually on the cloned PC for each network adapter.
 Is there any sdk/api to set them programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

I am able to change all the advanced adapter properties using [Intel® PROSet for Windows PowerShell* Software](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/000023545.html?sf85886126=1) .